# How to apply a function to multiple columns of a Dask Data Frame in parallel?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, dask

I have a Dask Dataframe for which I would like to compute skewness for a list of columns and if this skewness exceeds a certain threshold, I correct it using log transformation. I am wondering whether there is a more efficient way of making `correct_skewness()` function work on multiple columns in parallel by removing the **for loop** in the `correct_skewness()` function below:

```py
import dask
import dask.array as da 
from scipy import stats

# Create a dataframe 
df = dask.datasets.timeseries()

df.head()

                      id     name         x         y
timestamp
2000-01-01 00:00:00  1032   Oliver  0.018604  0.089191
2000-01-01 00:00:01  1032  Norbert  0.666689 -0.979374
2000-01-01 00:00:02   991   Victor  0.027691 -0.474660
2000-01-01 00:00:03   979    Kevin  0.320067  0.656949
2000-01-01 00:00:04  1087    Zelda -0.462076  0.513409


def correct_skewness(columns=None, max_skewness=2):
    if columns is None:
        raise ValueError(
            f"columns argument is None. Please set columns argument to a list of columns"
        )


    for col in columns:
        skewness = stats.skew(df[col])
        max_val = df[col].max().compute()
        min_val = df[col].min().compute()

        if abs(skewness) > max_skewness and (max_val > 1 or min_val < 0):
            delta = 1.0
            if min_val < 0:
                delta = max(1, -min_val + 1)
            df[col] = da.log(delta + df[col])
    return df

df = correct_skewness(columns=['x', 'y'])
```

Comment: You probably want to look at the multiprocessing module.

Comment: ^ @JackMoody , this person would like to use Dask, not multiprocessing directly, which is totally reasonable.

Comment: Oh ok. I think you might find [this link](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/scheduler-overview.html) helpful. It details how you can use multiple workers at once (so you could use 4 workers instead of just 1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple things you can do to improve parallelism in this example:

You can use dask.array.stats.skew rather than statsmodels.skew.  You will have to `import dask.array.stats` explicitly

You can compute the min/max of all columns in one computation

```
    mins = [df[col].min() for col in cols]
    maxes = [df[col].min() for col in cols]
    skews = [da.stats.skew(df[col]) for col in cols]

    mins, maxes, skews = dask.compute(mins, maxes, skews)
```

Then you could do your if-logic and apply `da.log` as appropriate.  This still requires two passes over your data, but that should be a nice improvement over what you have now.